# Recursive method to revert text

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Can someone please explain me how this code reverts the users input(it's a recursion):

```
Procedure revert;
Var text:char;
Begin
  Read (text)
  If (text <> '.') Then revert;
  Write(text);
End;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it by an example.
Imagine the user types 'Hello.'

- He types the letter 'H'.
- As `text` equals 'H' the condition `(text <> '.')` is true.
- So `revert` is called once again.
- Now there is a second `text` variable on the stack and it is going to
  be filled with the second letter the user enters. In this case it's
  'e'.
- The condition `(text <> '.')` is true again. So `revert` is    called
  once again.
- Now there is a third `text` variable on the stack and it is going to
  be filled with the third letter the user enters. In this case it's
  'l'.
- The condition `(text <> '.')` is true again. So `revert` is called
  once again.
- Now there is a fourth `text` variable on the stack and it is going to
  be filled with the third letter the user enters. In this case it's
  'l'.
- The condition `(text <> '.')` is true again. So `revert` is called
  once again.
- Now there is a fifth `text` variable on the stack and it is going to
  be filled with the fifth letter the user enters. In this case it's
  'o'.
- The condition `(text <> '.')` is true again. So `revert` is called
  once again.
- Now there is a sixth `text` variable on the stack and it is going to
  be filled with the sixth letter the user enters. In this case it's
  '.'.
- Now the condition `(text <> '.')` is false! `revert` is not going to
  be called.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's '.'.
- The sixth call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the sixth `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: The fifth call to
  `revert`.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's 'o'.
- The fifth call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the fifth `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: The fourth call to
  `revert`.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's 'l'.
- The fourth call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the fourth `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: The third call to
  `revert`.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's 'l'.
- The third call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the third `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: The second call to
  `revert`.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's 'e'.
- The second call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the second `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: The initial call
  to `revert`.
- The value of the topmost `text` variable will be written to the
  console. In this case it's 'H'.
- The initial call to `revert` is done now. It's cleaning the stack so
  the first `text` variable will be removed from it. The program is
  going back to the position where it has come from: We don't know it.
  Maybe the program ends
- The string '.olleH' appeared on the screen.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.*;
class revstr
{
    static String ans="";
    static String rev (String str)
    {
        if(str.length()==0)
            return ans;
        else
        {
            ans+=str.charAt(str.length()-1);
            return rev(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a java based program

Comment: It doesn't explain how or why the pascal snippet works.